# php echo drop down not working syntax please

Tags: php

i have a snippet here of a drop down box populated from mysql. nothing works beyond the end of the loop. it never gets to the 'made it' text. how can i debug this problem or can anyone help with the syntax

Bill

```
<?php
         echo "<select value='user_name' name='user_name'>";


          $sql = "SELECT * FROM healthcare.staff_template";

          $result = mysql_query($sql)or die (mysql_error());
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) or die (mysql_error()))
                {

                 echo "<option value="; 
                 echo($row["staff_name"]);
                 echo ">";
                 echo($row["staff_name"]);
                 echo "</option>";             
                }
                echo "</select>";
                echo "Made it";
        ?>
```

Comment: Remove code or die (mysql_error())  from while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`or die (mysql_error())` kills your program as soon as there are no more rows.